# Difference between rows in the same coulm for values which met specific conditions

Tags: spotfire, tibco

here's my input and my desidered output. Problem Is: I have a columns for product, price, and date and I want to build a cross table where I can see the price of the day before for every product.

How can I calculate column d-1 (day - 1) in my data table? Should I use Intersect/Over functions? What If I want to calculate my d-1 column on-the-fly in a cross table?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have some options here, depending on how you want to display everything.

If all you want is an overall snapshot of how it changed between Today and Yesterday, probably the simplest thing to do is the following:

```
Avg(If([DATE]=Date(DateTimeNow()),[Price],NULL)) as [Today's Price], 
Avg(If([DATE]=Date(DateAdd("day",-1,DateTimeNow())),[Price],NULL)) as [Yesterday's Price], 
Avg(If([DATE]=Date(DateTimeNow()),[Price],NULL)) - Avg(If([DATE]=Date(DateAdd("day",-1,DateTimeNow())),[Price],NULL)) as [d-1]
```

This can be very useful for a dashboard or summary, and if you replace the "DateTimeNow" component with a Document Property controlled by an Input field, this can quickly show your user the change on a specific day.

The Over functions could still be quite useful, especially if you're using a date hierarchy of some form.
It will update on the fly to accommodate the columns grouped across the top, so if you're displaying by date, you can see how it's been changing each day, and if you're displaying by month, you can see it that way instead.

```
Avg([Price]) as [Avg Price], 
Avg([Price]) - Avg([Price]) OVER (PreviousPeriod([Axis.Columns])) as [Avg Price Change]
```